# Include only properties that are instantiated when serializing to Json

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have a class that I referenced from an internal nuget package

```
public class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set;}
     public int Age{ get; set;}
}
```

and I am using System.Text.Json to serialize the instantiated message.

When I initialized an instance of the class, say for example

```
Person p = new Person() {Name = "Abraham"};
```

and serialized it, the resulting string still includes the Age property.

```
Person {
     "Name": "Abraham",
     "Age": 0
}
```

May I know how will I be able to serialize an instance of a class with only the initialized properties included.

Comment: `Age` *is* "initialized" though... to its default value.  Did you want to use `int?` instead?

Comment: no, as I have said in the first line, the class is from an internal nuget package to which I have no control to change the type to a nullable.

Comment: You could potentially write a custom JSON serializer which ignores `int` properties with the value `0`.  Or perhaps write your own class(es) and transpose to that before serializing.

Comment: Writing my own classes is an option but I have a requirement to use that class from the package.

Answer (score 1):

you can use JsonIgnoreCondition option

```
string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer
.Serialize(p, new JsonSerializerOptions {WriteIndented=true, DefaultIgnoreCondition = 
System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault});
```

or as a property attribute

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have thought aboyut the use of JsonIgnoreCndition.WhenWritingDefault, although there are numerical properties that I need to release in the data even though their value is 0, and there are some that I really don't need to. Using that will remove those properties.

Comment: I know what I need. Clearly stated above.